# Windows 8 causes 100% usage of Seagate 1 TB hard disk

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, hard-drive

This year I upgraded my 500 GB hard disk to 1000 GB (both from Seagate). At that time I was on Windows 7. Everything worked without troubles.

Now I upgraded to Windows 8, with all latest updates.

When I turn on my computer I can see a lot of workload on my hard disk. Sometime it's using 100%.

I don't know what it does since I never run any data-intensive apps. I use Visual Web developer and some browsers like Google Chrome, Firefox, as well as Sumatra PDF or VLC.

How can I find out what makes my computer use the hard disk so much?

Answer (score 0):

Install [the WPT](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx) and capture a xperf trace.

Copy this into a .txt file, rename it to .cmd and run it from a command prompt with admin rights:

```
@echo off
echo Press a key when ready to start...
pause

echo .
echo ...Capturing...
echo .

xperf -on PROC_THREAD+LOADER+DISK_IO+DISK_IO_INIT -stackwalk DiskReadInit+DiskWriteInit+DiskFlushInit -BufferSize 1024 -MinBuffers 256 -MaxBuffers 256 -MaxFile 256 -FileMode Circular

echo Press a key when you want to stop...
pause
echo .
echo ...Stopping...
echo .

xperf -stop -d diskio.etl
```

Watch the video how to see what causes the disk IO:

**Defrag Tools: #44 - WPT - DiskIO Analysis**

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-44-WPT-DiskIO-Analysis

If you're unsure, zip and upload the file, I'll take a look at it.