# Unusual disk use on Windows 8.1 100% disk usage ONLY when running particular programs

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, task-manager

by opening the task manager I found out this weird thing happening:

The disk usage spikes to 95-100% when I am running programs such as C-Cleaner, or Avast.
Sometimes it shows a regular pattern: it peaks at 75% and then after 5 seconds it jumps to 100%, then again at 75%, then 100% and so on periodically.

If I am not using either of the programs above, it goes down to 10% as it should be

Now, everything else seems to run at normal speed when the above things happens, I can normally and, hopefully, safely run other applications while this thing is happening.

Can someone explain me why this is happening? It has never happened before I believe...

I am wondering if this could be the same problem shown here:

[Windows 8.1 100% disk usage](https://superuser.com/questions/827583/windows-8-1-100-disk-usage)
[Windows 8.1 Update 1 Disk Usage 100%](https://superuser.com/questions/759152/windows-8-1-update-1-disk-usage-100)

Comment: capture a xperf trace of the high DISkIO and share it: http://superuser.com/a/616353/174557

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite normal unless you have an SSD or you are experiencing slow downs.
Avast! is an antivirus and most antiviruses do background scanning which causes the heavy disk usage.
CCleaner also needs to analyze a huge number of files and folders to figure out which ones to clean.

You may see the same behaviors when you launch a game or when it is loading.
If you don't have an SSD, 100% disk usage is likely to occur every time you start these kinds of apps.